To xiaohouzi79 about negative number
I saw you deleted a post about Chinese negative number. 
The Google translate link that you were given translated "-5" as "零下5" which is used for temperatures rather than numbers.

I have now corrected the comment in that question. However, my point stands, the asker didn't put any effort into finding the answer themselves and the answer is available in a standard dictionary.
